# host name may not be null error in android

Tags: java, android, http-post

I get the error "host name may not be null error " in my Android app.

This is my code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://sub_domain.domain.com/service/api");
httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try {
        httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I use a sub-domain so I can't put 'www' in my url because it's another sub domain.
I have Internet permission in my manifest file.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edit : It's impossible to access to this url with a GET method.

Without '_' in my subdomain, it's okay.

Comment: check the way url is encoded. any spaces should be eliminated.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537522/host-name-may-not-be-null-in-httpresponse-execute-for-android. Similar to your question

Comment: Have you tried it with a subdomain that doesn't have an underscore in it? They can cause problems.

Comment: no spaces in my url and with URLEncoder.encode(URL); I have the same issue.

Comment: I can't. "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look this link. Apache doesnt support underscore

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-911

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered Similar Errors when my net connectivity is down in the middle of running of my application. I have Used Async Task And when the Async task doesnt Find the link, /it gives Similar result of Window Leak.